# Trigger that restricts by date

Tags: sql, oracle

Im trying to create a trigger that restricts the amount a reader can read in a given month.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE trigger Readings_Limit
Before update or insert on reading
for each row declare
readingcount integer;
max_read integer := 5;
Begin
Select count(*) into readingcount
from (select * 
from Reading
where to_char(DateRead, 'YYYY-MM') = to_char(DateRead, 'YYYY-MM'))
where employeeid = :new.employeeid;
if :old.employeeid = :new.employeeid then
return;
else
if readingcount >= max_read then
raise_application_error (-20000, 'An Employee can only read 5 per month');
end if;
end if;
end;
```

This restricts the reader to 5 max in total no matter the month, i can't seem to get it to be 5 max each month. any ideas greatly appreciated!

Comment: I'm not sure quite what you're aiming for here: `to_char(DateRead, 'YYYY-MM') = to_char(DateRead, 'YYYY-MM')` but read it to yourself again and ponder whether it can possibly be doing anything useful.

Answer (score 0):

Try to rewrite your trigger like this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE trigger Readings_Limit
  Before update or insert on reading
  for each row
declare
  readingcount integer;
  max_read integer := 5;
Begin
  Select count(*) into readingcount
    from Reading
    where DateRead between trunc(sysdate,'MM') and last_day(sysdate)
      and employeeid = :new.employeeid;

  if :old.employeeid = :new.employeeid then
    return;
  else
    if readingcount >= max_read then
      raise_application_error (-20000, 'An Employee can only read 5 per month');
    end if;
  end if;
end;
```

You add actual month into yout select and you avoid unnecessary date conversion.

I don't understand the condition

```
if :old.employeeid = :new.employeeid then
```

Does it mean, the trigger should not fire on updates? In this case it is better to make trigger only for insert or use clause `if inserting then...`

Comment: When you select table `READING` inside a row-level trigger based on table `READING` you will get an `ORA-04091: table USER.READING is mutating, trigger/function may not see it` error. `TRUNC(SYSDATE)` give the current day, not the first day of the current month, it must be `TRUNC(SYSDATE, 'MM')`

Comment: Ok, trunc(sysdate, 'MM') is right. But the trigger is working on my 10g database. I made a primary key constraint on reading(employeeid, dateread) and it works. I get an ORA-20000 error after 5 inserts...

Comment: You will get the `ORA-04091` on UPDATE of the table.

Comment: Related to the fact that `ORA-04091` is not raised I found this one: [Why am I NOT getting a mutating table error in trigger?](http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/29244/why-am-i-not-getting-a-mutating-table-error-in-trigger)

Comment: In this case I would consider need of update on the table. If it is necessary then you must use additional statement triggers and package according to this article: ["Avoiding Mutating Tables"](https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/ASKTOM.download_file?p_file=6551198119097816936)

Comment: I tried adopting this but it just gave me 5 in total, so i couldn't add more readings in a different month

Answer (score 0):

In order to properly create this validation using a trigger a procedure should be created to obtain user-specified locks so the validation can be correctly serialized in a multi-user environment.

```
PROCEDURE request_lock
  (p_lockname                     IN     VARCHAR2
  ,p_lockmode                     IN     INTEGER  DEFAULT dbms_lock.x_mode
  ,p_timeout                      IN     INTEGER  DEFAULT 60
  ,p_release_on_commit            IN     BOOLEAN  DEFAULT TRUE
  ,p_expiration_secs              IN     INTEGER  DEFAULT 600)
IS
  -- dbms_lock.allocate_unique issues implicit commit, so place in its own
  -- transaction so it does not affect the caller
  PRAGMA AUTONOMOUS_TRANSACTION;
  l_lockhandle                   VARCHAR2(128);
  l_return                       NUMBER;
BEGIN
  dbms_lock.allocate_unique
    (lockname                       => p_lockname
    ,lockhandle                     => p_lockhandle
    ,expiration_secs                => p_expiration_secs);
  l_return := dbms_lock.request
    (lockhandle                     => l_lockhandle
    ,lockmode                       => p_lockmode
    ,timeout                        => p_timeout
    ,release_on_commit              => p_release_on_commit);
  IF (l_return not in (0,4)) THEN
    raise_application_error(-20001, 'dbms_lock.request Return Value ' || l_return);
  END IF;
  -- Must COMMIT an autonomous transaction
  COMMIT;
END request_lock;
```

To have the least impact on scalability the serialization should be done at the finest level, which for this constraint is per employeeid and month. Types may be used in order to create variables to store this information for each row before the constraint is checked after the statement has completed. These types can be either defined in the database or (from Oracle 12c) in package specifications.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE reading_rec
AS OBJECT
  (employeeid NUMBER(10) -- Note should match the datatype of reading.employeeid
  ,dateread   DATE);

CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE readings_tbl
AS TABLE OF reading_rec;
```

The procedure and types can then be used in a compound trigger (assuming at least Oracle 11, this will need to be split into individual triggers in earlier versions)

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER too_many_readings
  FOR INSERT OR UPDATE ON reading
  COMPOUND TRIGGER

  -- Table to hold identifiers of inserted/updated readings
  g_readings readings_tbl;

BEFORE STATEMENT 
IS
BEGIN
  -- Reset the internal readings table
  g_readings := readings_tbl();
END BEFORE STATEMENT; 

AFTER EACH ROW
IS
BEGIN
  -- Store the inserted/updated readings
  IF (  INSERTING
     OR :new.employeeid  <> :old.employeeid
     OR :new.dateread <> :old.dateread)
  THEN           
    g_readings.EXTEND;
    g_readings(g_readings.LAST) := reading_rec(:new.employeeid, :new.dateread);
  END IF;
END AFTER EACH ROW;

AFTER STATEMENT
IS
  CURSOR csr_readings
  IS
    SELECT DISTINCT
           employeeid
          ,trunc(dateread,'MM') monthread
    FROM TABLE(g_readings)
    ORDER BY employeeid
            ,trunc(dateread,'MM');
  CURSOR csr_constraint_violations
    (p_employeeid reading.employeeid%TYPE
    ,p_monthread  reading.dateread%TYPE)
  IS
    SELECT count(*) readings
    FROM reading rdg
    WHERE rdg.employeeid = p_employeeid
    AND trunc(rdg.dateread, 'MM') = p_monthread
    HAVING count(*) > 5;
  r_constraint_violation csr_constraint_violations%ROWTYPE;
BEGIN
  -- Check if for any inserted/updated readings there exists more than
  -- 5 readings for the same employee in the same month. Serialise the
  -- constraint for each employeeid so concurrent transactions do not
  -- affect each other
  FOR r_reading IN csr_readings LOOP
    request_lock('TOO_MANY_READINGS_'
      || r_reading.employeeid
      || '_' || to_char(r_reading.monthread, 'YYYYMM'));
    OPEN csr_constraint_violations(r_reading.employeeid, r_reading.monthread);
    FETCH csr_constraint_violations INTO r_constraint_violation;
    IF csr_constraint_violations%FOUND THEN
      CLOSE csr_constraint_violations;
      raise_application_error(-20001, 'Employee ' || r_reading.employeeid
        || ' now has ' || r_constraint_violation.readings
        || ' in ' || to_char(r_reading.monthread, 'FMMonth YYYY'));
    ELSE
      CLOSE csr_constraint_violations;
    END IF;
  END LOOP;
END AFTER STATEMENT;

END;
```

Comment: You cannot set single components of `g_readings` when you defined a table of objects

Answer (score -1):

You need to set the month you are looking at, so if you are considering the current month, make the inner query read like this:

```
( select * from Reading 
where to_char(DateRead,'YYYY-MM') = to_char(DateRead,'YYYY-MM')
and to_char(sysdate,'YYYY-MM') = to_char(DateRead,'YYYY-MM'))
```

that way it will always compare to the current month and should move as your date moves.

Comment: Why do you convert a date into a string? Also `WHERE to_char(DateRead,'YYYY-MM') = to_char(DateRead,'YYYY-MM')` is pretty useless!

Comment: You're right! I was thinking it was restricting the dates, but it should have read as I think someone else said, where the month of DateRead equals the month of today: to_char(dateread,'YYYY-MM') = to_char(sysdate,'YYYY-MM') - so the first where condition could be eliminated entirely!